# not able to extend azure SQL vm data disk size from 4TB to 8Tb using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-sql-database

I  am not able to extend azure SQL vm data disk size from 4TB to 8TB using Terraform
It's giving error me the error

> Error updating managed disk.disks can not be resized beyond 4TB when attached to vm

Note: this happens although the VM is in stopped (deallocated state)

Comment: Hello @Prasenjit Roy,  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk#resize-a-managed-disk-in-the-azure-portal), You can now resize your managed disks without deallocating your VM.

To register for the feature, use the following command:

```
Register-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName "LiveResize" -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Compute"
```

It may take a few minutes for registration to take complete. To confirm that you've registered, use the following command:

```
Register-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName "LiveResize" -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Compute"
```

> Note - The new size should be greater than the existing disk size. The
> maximum allowed is 4,095 GB for OS disks. (It's possible to expand the
> VHD blob beyond that size, but the OS works only with the first 4,095
> GB of space.)

[image]